# Error: Google Play Services keep stopping

Tags: samsung

This errorr message keeps flashing. I tried the solutions offered but on Settings the google play services app does not open the disable or force stop buttons.  I tried uninstalling updates but I get the message that it can't uninstall because google is an device administrator. Switching off my mobile data and wifi did not work, switching the device off and on did not work.  Any other advice?

Answer (score 4):

Open *Settings/Apps/Google Play Services/Storage.*

Click *Manager Storage* and Click *Clear All Data.*

Then Re-install [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms).